# Redirecting to new page when clicked on a date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I wrote a code for opening the date picker when clicked on the image:
Here is the screen shot:
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
And here is the code:
`HTML`

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 127px; left: 31px;">Click
            on image to enter period start date:</div>

        <img src='./img/calendar.png' id="datepickerImage"
            style="position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 126px; height: 75px;" />
```

`javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true,
                }).hide().click(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
                    $("#datepicker").show();
                });

            });
```

The datepicker opens successfully. When any date on the datepicker is clicked, I want it to be redirected to next page. How can I do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/268/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-dialog) method.

> onSelect Type: Function() A callback function when a date is selected.
>   The function receives the date text and date picker instance as
>   parameters.

As @Learner has mentioned in comment with fiddle link.

And to redirect use `window.location.href` with full url.

```
window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com'
```

Comment: Vote up the question if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
            }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
       window.open("yourURL", "_self");
   });
   $("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
                $("#datepicker").show();
            });
        });
```

More info on window.open here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp